# How do I tell Node.js HTTP server-side to send response binary data using a certain encoding/endianness?

Tags: node.js, http, encoding, binary, endianness

I am writing some node.js server-side code and bumping into a problem with encoding/endian-ness. The code looks like this:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
. . .
res.writeHead(200, {
“content-disposition”: “attachment;filename=” + fileName,
‘content-type’: ‘application/octet-stream',
‘content-length’: file.length
});
res.write(file,“binary”);
res.end();
```

the file contents on the server begins with “FFD8 FFE0”. I am using Chrome on a MacBook Pro. The file Chrome saves to my local filesystem begins with “D8FF E0FF”

I used wireshark and see the values being sent to the browser are “D8FF E0FF” which is not what I want. What can I do in node to get the correct encoding?

Added/Updated: I am using Hexdump -n 32 on the server (it's running Centos) to see the file contents. And I use Hex Fiend on MacOS 11.2.1 to view the file contents. I am using Wireshark 3.4.3 (v3.4.3-0-g6ae6cd335aa9) on MacOS.

Comment: When you run `od -t x1 <file>` on the client and server, do you get a different output? Please edit your question to include how you're looking at these binary files.

Comment: Also, do you get different behavior if you omit the `"binary"` encoding argument altogether?

Comment: Got this on the server:
od -N10 -t x1 White.mjpeg 
0000000 d8 ff e0 ff 10 00 46 4a 46 49
And this on my Mac:
od -N10 -t x1 White.mjpeg
0000000    d8  ff  e0  ff  10  00  46  4a  46  49                        
Thanks for teaching me about od. Next, I'll look at why the endian order is reverse on the ESP32 HTTPclient library to download the same file. I'll post results here. Seems like I might just be crazy. Sorry if I am.

Comment: I am crazy. I'm sorry to waste everyone's time. I can't duplicate the problem tonight.